# Prove that, there no solution for $\left\{a_1,a_2,...,a_{16} \right\}\in \mathbb{R} $

Tags: calculus, polynomials, proof-writing, systems-of-equations

Prove that, there no solution

> $$\begin{cases} 
> a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+...+a_{16}^2=2017\\
> a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_{16}=1009\\
> \end{cases}$$
>   for $\left\{a_1,a_2,...,a_{16} \right\}\in \mathbb{R} $

I tried $(a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_{16})^2=a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+...+a_{16}^2+2(a_1a_2+a_1a_3+...+a_{15}a_{16})$ but I stuck.

Comment: @user8734617 i think in all scenarios the discriminant will turn negative

Comment: I was being silly... Just deleted the comment.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll delete mine.

Comment: It seems that you didn't notice that the answer you chose is wrong. Anyway, that is your choice. LOL

Comment: @Nirvana thank you. I deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the inequality
$$
16\sum_{i=1}^{16}a_i^2\geqslant \Big(\sum_{i=1}^{16}a_i\Big)^2,
$$
if such $a_i$ exist, we have
$$
16\times2017\geqslant 1009^2.
$$
This is impossible.